# How can I access and insert dates into my database? Node.JS & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

So, I'm writing a Calendar application using Node.JS and MongoDB. But I'm having trouble adding information from the database to current calendar.

Here is the error I am receiving when trying to load `LocalHost:3000/init`

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
>          at /home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/server.js:30:13
>          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>          at next (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>          at Route.dispatch (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>          at /home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
>          at Function.process_params (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
>          at next (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
>          at jsonParser (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:100:40)
>          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/patrick/Desktop/Javascript/CalandarApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Here's the Javascript:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

//Connect to MongoDB
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var db = require('mongodb');
mongoskin.db("mongodb://localhost:3000/testDB", {w: 0});

//Creates Express Application
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));


//is necessary for parsing POST request
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

console.log('Express server started on port 3000');

app.get('/init', function(req, res){
    db.event.insert({ 
        text:"Test Event A", 
        start_date: new Date(2016,5,1),
        end_date:   new Date(2016,5,5)
    });
    db.event.insert({ 
        text:"Test Event B", 
        start_date: new Date(2016,5,3),
        end_date:   new Date(2016,5,8),
        color: "#DD8616"
    });

    res.send("Test Events were added to the Database")
});


app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    db.event.find().toArray(function(err, data){
        //set id property for all records
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            data[i].id = data[i]._id;

        //output response
        res.send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I don't think you set up the collection properly. Shouldn't it be something like `db.collection('event').insert()`. Also it seems you're using a `.get` for a `.post` route. If you're inserting information into the database, you'd want to use a `.post` not `.get`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined` because `db.event` is undefined. You need to use `db.bind('COLLECTION_NAME')` to bind the mongoskin events to the collection name.

Also, `db` should be created using mongoskin and you don't need to `require('mongodb')`.

Your code can start out with this:

```
// load mongoskin module
var mongo = require('mongoskin');

// connect to local mongo database
var db = mongo.db('127.0.0.1:27017/test');

// bind db.event to db.collection('event') so you can use db.event.insert
db.bind('event');

// rest of tour code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the insert code:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var db = new Db(dbName, new Server(host, port), {safe: true});
db.open(function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    db.collection('collectionName', function (err, collection) {
      if (err) {
        mongodb.close();
        return callback(err);
      }
      collection.insert(post, {
        safe: true
      }, function (err) {
        mongodb.close();
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null);
      });
    });
  });
```

Here is the access code:

```
 db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    db.collection('collectionName', function(err, collection) {
      if(err) {
        mongodb.close();
        return callback(err);
      }
      collection.findOne({
        query Condition
      }, function(err, result) {
        db.close();
        if(err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, result);
      })
    });
  });
```